# Unable to install SQL Server (setup.exe)

Tags: sql-server

I used SQL Server 2019 express version on my laptop butI uninstalled. Now I am trying to install SQL Server 2019 Developer edition but I get an error:

> Exit code (Decimal): -2068119551 Exit message: Cannot find registry key 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\150\ConfigurationState'.
> Error description: Invalid command line argument. Consult the windows installer SDK for detailed command line help.

Environment: Dell/Inspiron/Windows 10 Home/16gb ram/256 SSD / 1TB HDD /Corei7

Can anyone help me how to solve the problem? Thanks

PS: attaching screenshot for kind reference
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try below options, based on the [reference article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/216059/unable-to-install-sql-server-setupexe.html)

1. Run the setup.exe again, repair the installation.

[image: Repair installation]

2. Run the Setup.exe as administrator
3. See whether you have clearly uninstalled the previous SQL Server setup and try again.
4. Did you modify the registry setting earlier. If so, please revert the changes and try the installation. Eg., changing the default installation to D:, instead of C: etc.

Answer (score -1):

I fed up the below problem

**Unable to install SQL Server (setup.exe).
Exit code (Decimal): -2068119551 Exit message: Cannot find registry key 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\150\ConfigurationState'. Error description: The specified service does not exist as an installed service.**

I fixed the above problem

DR-2033 avatar image
Click to vote
1 Vote"
1
DR-2033 answered • Dec 21 2021 at 4:03 AM | EricK-0825 commented • Mar 21 2022 at 3:20 AM

[Unable to install SQL Server (setup.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/668708/ssd-showing-incorrect-bytes-per-sector-win-11-sql.html?childToView=670292#answer-670292)