# Connecting a C# Console Application to a MySQL (PHPmyAdmin) database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, phpmyadmin

I'm a software engineering student and we've just started learning about Entity Framework and how it helps connect your App to a database to achieve data persistence.

There is one small issue, Everyone including the teacher is using SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio which is auto configured on Entity Framework because they're from the same company.
SQL Server and SSMS just refuse to work on my laptop no matter how hard I try so I want to use PHPMyAdmin as a database, I don't know how to make it work though... Any help please ?

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server so make sure you are using the SQLClient class in the c# code.   The issue is with the connection string.  You need to create the database in the server.  Do not use LocalDb when a database is attached to the server.  Instead use Server=myServerName.   Your server probably has more than one database attach so use Initial Catalog=myDataBase .  Most likely the server defaults to the user login for credentials and you should use Integrated Security=true; (not a username and password).  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: *SQL Server and SSMS just refuse to work on my laptop no matter how hard I try* - with what error?

Comment: *PHPMyAdmin as a database* - phpma is not a database. *which is auto configured on Entity Framework because they're from the same company* - this isn't actually true

Comment: *Everyone including the teacher is using SQL Server* - don't buck the trend; get SQLS working. All databases are not the same. You don't need to have SQLS on the same PC you have - any other machine on the network will suffice. You could even sign up for a free account from Azure and run a free SQLS DB in it, then you don't even need to bother about installing stuff..

Comment: @jdweng *"make sure you are using the SQLClient class in the c# code"* - mm, don't really remember the last time I wrote `SqlClient` in a project that uses EF, even for raw

Comment: @CaiusJard "Unable to install SQL Server (setup.exe)" , as U can see , it doesn't really say much.

Comment: @CaiusJard I will try the Azure solution and see where that gets me. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616132/unable-to-install-sql-server-setup-exe - there will be some more info logged than just that

Comment: et SSMS working so you can database (or attach an existing one).